# Wrong length displayed for audio file

Tags: music-player, google-play-music, audiobooks

So I have an audio book in a single `mp3` file that's over 5 hours long. On my computer all players display it's length correctly, however on my phone [Smart AudioBook Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer) and the Play Music app both says that it's only 11 minutes long. Rockbox picks up the length correctly.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it **without using a different app**?

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely a VBR mp3.  as a DJ we have seen this a lot, The VBR is never detected correctly as the length of the playback is not proportional to the length of the file. 
With DJ software we have to prescan the files to determine their real length, obviously your application is only expecting FBR files and not VBR.
You could put it through something like Audacity on a PC and convert it to Fixed Bit Rate. but that is you only real solution, I think.

Comment: Well I've thought of that but as most of my music is VBR and it's picked up correctly I don't think that this is the issue. What's the easiest way to see if it's VBR?  Because I'm pretty sure that it isn't - it's 40Kbit/s.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik You could try [MP3Info](http://ibiblio.org/mp3info/) (for Mac: [MP3-Info](http://www.cdfinder.de/en/en/en/mp3info.html)) which should be able to display technical details on MP3 files: *display various techincal aspects of an MP3 file including playing time, bit-rate, sampling frequency and other...*

Comment: @Izzy Bonus points for finding a tool written by a CM dev :)

Comment: @RichardBorcsik *LOL* Of course I mad sure... xD